# Creating a .txt file from scratch

Tags: java, python, c, assembly, microcontroller

I'm working on a microcontroller and I'm trying to write some data from some sensors into a .txt file on the SDcard and later on place the sd card in a card reader and read the data on the PC.

Does anyone know how to write a .txt file from scratch for a FAT32 file system? I don't have any predefined code/methods/functions to call, I'll need to create the code from nothin.

It's not a question for a specific programming language, that is why I tagged more than one. I can later on convert the code from C or Java to my programming language of choice. But I can't  seem to find such low level methods/functions in any type of language :)

Any ideas?

Comment: More details. What kind of microcontroller?

Comment: Instead of tagging your question with every programming language under the sun, it would be more helpful if you told us which microcontroller you are targetting.

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you've done a lot of research. A simple google search finds a few implementations of FAT-32 among the first hits: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fat32+microcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) is quite good, and highly portable. It has support for FAT12, FAT16 and FAT32, long filenames, seeking, reading and writing (most of these things can be switched on and off to change the memory footprint).
If you're really tight on memory there's also Petit FatFs, but it doesn't have write support by default and adding it would take some work.

After [mounting](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/en/mount.html) the drive you'd simply [open](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/en/open.html) a file to create it. For example:

```
FATFS fatFs;
FIL newFile;

// The drive number may differ 
if (f_mount(0, &fatFs) != FR_OK) {
  // Something went wrong
}

if (f_open(&newFile, "/test.txt", FA_WRITE | FA_OPEN_ALWAYS) != FR_OK) {
  // Something went wrong
}
```

---

If you really need to create the file using only your own code you'll have to traverse the FAT, looking for empty space and then creating new LFN entries (where you store the filename) and DIRENTs (which specify the clusters on the disk that will hold the file data).
I can't see any reason for doing this except if this is some kind of homework / lab exercise. In any case you should do some [reading about the FAT structure](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS24/Slides/FileSysDataStructs/FileSysDataStructs.html) first and return with some more specific questions once you've got started.

Answer (score 1):

In JAVA you can do like this

```
Writer output = null;
String text = "This is test message";
File file = new File("write.txt"); 
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
output.write(text);
output.close();  
System.out.println("Your file has been written");
```